# Let A, B, C be sets such that $A\cap B=A \cap C$ and $ A\cup B=A \cup C$. Prove that $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I proof this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: welcome to maths stack exchange. You are encouraged to include your attempts when you post a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$.

(1) If $x\in A$, then $x\in A \cap B$ but $x\notin A \cap C$ contradiction.

(2) If $x\notin A$, then $x\in A \cup B$ but $x\notin A \cup C$ contradiction.

Similarly we can show $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$ leads to similar contradictions.